# Salesforce SCIM endpoint returns 500

Tags: rest-api, user-management, identity

When i trying to add a using scim endpoints it gives me following error.

```
{"Errors":[{"description":"Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at input location [1,3]","code":500}]}
```

It seems like a error when parsing the json payload.

My request looks like this,

```
curl -v -k  --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' --data "{"schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],"userName":"user1@scim.org","name":{"familyName":"DarRay"},"emails":["darrayuser@wso2.com"],"entitlements":[{"value":"00e90000001STRnAAO","display":"ChatterFreeUser"}]}" https://MY_SF_DOMAIN/services/apexrest/scim/v1/Users
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake..

Changing request to use single quotes in the payload solved the issue.

```
curl -v -k  --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' --data '{"schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],"userName":"user1@scim.org","name":{"familyName":"DarRay"},"emails":["darrayuser@wso2.com"],"entitlements":[{"value":"00e90000001STRnAAO","display":"ChatterFreeUser"}]}' https://MY_SF_DOMAIN/services/apexrest/scim/v1/Users
```

Just post the issue in the case someone would find useful.